# How can I write the monadic bind operator (>>=) on paper?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

`>>=` takes a lot of dashes of the pencil to write down on paper and I always manage to make it look really ugly. Are there more convenient (and hopefully "standard") ways to write down this and other related monadic operators such as `return` and `>=>`?

Comment: Practice caligraphy? I'd love to write everything as a flat line, since it's easier, but then no one would know what I'm saying.

Comment: Print it out like a sane person. Also seriously, off-topic.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: You can't print things out on a blackboard :P And if its too off topic, who should I ask it then?

Comment: @missingno StackOverflow sadly doesn't say "if it isn't on topic anywhere else then it is on topic here" rather, it tries to limit questions to code-snippets or algorithmic ones with concrete answers.  I would try on IRC and the ML.

Comment: @missingno You could also try asking on [/r/haskell](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell).

Comment: You could use category theory notation: \eta for return and \mu for join, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)#Formal_definition